# Is it bad karma to use Silverlight 4 but keep using .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Is it bad karma to use Silverlight 4 but keep using .NET Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what I do.  The only downside I've found is the lack of Ria-Services.

Other than that limitation I haven't found any compelling reasons not to do it.

Comment: +1 I agree, there is very little friction switching to SL4 but moving to .NET 4 on the server is a much bigger deal.

Comment: @Anthony That's been the big hold up for us.  Switching to SL4 was easy but getting IT to upgrade servers to .NET 4 has caused many headaches.